# jquery huge request for fullcalendar mark timeranges

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i have a huge request for the jquery fullcalendar, i need a solution to mark some timeranges in the day- and agenda-view like the today marker but not the the hole day only a range for example from 8:00 to 12:00. I will be glad if somebody have an solution or an idea how i can make this. For example modification of the fullcalendar code.

Update: I saw a solution nearly my problem here 
[Work time in fullcalendar [Solution]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520143/work-time-in-fullcalendar-solution)

i have been tested this solution but i have one strange effect. the markers are shiftet to the right side.

Kindes Regards

Sinderella

Answer (score 2):

You have to open d.js and search for:

```
{agenda:0.5},minTime:8,maxTime:19}
```

Change the values for the ones you want and this is it.

Comment: in new new version of `fullcalendar.min.js` search `dragOpacity:{agenda:.5},minTime`

Answer (score 0):

In new version of `fullcalendar.min.js` search `dragOpacity:{agenda:.5},minTime` and update `,minTime:8,maxTime:12` to restrict agenda view to 8.00-12.00 slot.